# ? is the only output for all unicode above U+0080 in java

Tags: java, unicode

I created a small program to display regional language character but the output that i get on command prompt is '?' only ,for all unicode above U+0080 including U+0080(excluding english alphabet characters) .
i am attaching my code.

```
public class Test{
public static void main(String args[]){
char uniChar = '\u0080';
System.out.println(uniChar);
}
}
```

the output that i am getting is
[image: the output that i am getting is]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Read up on character encoding, and always remember to [search first](https://www.google.com/#q=site:stackoverflow.com+java+println+question+mark) before asking.

Comment: Windows command only supports the 8bit character set of the user's locale, e.g. windows-1252 if in Western Europe. When in Western Europe, you should be able to print U+0000 -> U+00FF

Comment: @Alastair McCormack is there any other  way to print that character

Comment: According to https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Unicode/Character_reference/0000-0FFF, U+0080 is a control character, as are many between, U+0080 and U+009F. Try jumping to U+00A0